# pod repo push failing silently on azure pipeline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines, cocoapods

While doing **pod repo push** on azure pipeline, if some error occurs, **pod repo push** is failing silently.

for example, On running this command on pipeline -> **pod repo push REPO_NAME MyLib.podspec --verbose --allow-warnings**, I can see this error :

> **Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation),**

but still getting successful build on pipeline, is there any way to catch these silent failures and make the pipeline fail

Comment: What do you mean about 'failing silently', only because the command didn't fail the pipeline run? If you are based on bash, you can use exit 1 to force the pipeline to fail.

Comment: By failing silently, I mean, on running **pod repo push**, it was throwing linker error but it continues to run, and in pipeline getting a successful build, but what you said above answered my question. Thanks !! :)

Comment: Hi, I post an answer just now, could you please [accept it as the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) to end this question? This will help others who meet the same situation. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are based on bash, you can use `exit 1` to force the pipeline to fail.